# Check prime number in array

Tags: swift

Trying to write a check for Prime numbers in the array. The array is populated randomly. But when processing the array code does not work... What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

update 2
Filling the array correctly. But with the test simple number, something is wrong. Specifically what is wrong can not say, but the point is that the rules of a simple number sorting is not working.

```
import Foundation

func randomArray(var i:Int,var k:Int, var array: [Int]=[], var newArray: [Int]=[]) ->Int {
    for i=0;i<10;i++ {
        array.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    }
    for i=0;i<=array.count; i++ {
        for k=2; k<array[i]; k++ {
            if array[i] != 0 && array[i] != 1 && array[i]%k != 0 {
                newArray.append(array[i])
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray[i]
}

randomArray(0, k: 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? What goes wrong?

Comment: It's better if you can clarify what "does not work" mean. Do you to fill an array of length `k` at random and want to filter for prime numbers only?

Comment: @vardian that's not the problem, they have default values.

Comment: There is no reason to have `i` as a parameter. It can be a local variable.

Comment: Ah, same with `k`.

Comment: @CodeDifferent Thank you for the answer. Yea, you are right.

Comment: @ThomasW what do you mean?

Comment: Regarding the unnecessary parameters? In your code you're never using and then overwriting the values of `i` and `k`. Thus they don't need to be parameters they can just be local variables.

Comment: @ThomasW You mean this? for var i=0;i<=array.count; i++  and
        for  var k=2; k<array[i]; k++ without declare a variable like this randomArray(var i:Int,var k:Int)?

Comment: Yes, but it currently won't work since you're using `i` incorrectly at the end of your code in `return newArray[i]`.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this code, but the main problem is that the prime number check is incorrect. To determine if a number is prime, you need to check that it is not divisible by all numbers less than it. The current code will end up adding the same value to `newArray` multiple times. However, if a value is added to `newArray` and the `return 0` is not executed, the code will crash because `i` will be past the end of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you want to do.

a) If you want to generate an array of length `k` at random and filter for prime numbers, use the code below. Note that this can give give you an array of length between 0 to `k`, because they may be no prime in the randomly generated array, or every number generated was a prime:

```
func isPrime(num: Int) -> Bool {
    if num < 2 {
        return false
    }

    for i in 2..<num {
        if num % i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

func randomArray(len: Int) -> [Int] {
    var results = [Int]()

    for _ in 0..<len {
        results.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    }

    return results.filter(isPrime)
}
```

b) If you want an array of `k` primes, use this instead:

```
func randomPrimeArray(len: Int) -> [Int] {
    var results = [Int]()

    while results.count < len {
        let x = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
        if isPrime(x) {
            results.append(x)
        }
    }

    return results
}
```

Comment: My case is letter A, thank you. The separation into two functions seems logical.

Comment: Why use an underscore? `for _ in 0..<len`

Comment: "Why use an underscore? for _ in 0..<len"  - Because the variable on that place has never used inside the for loop or program. Try to write in Xcode as "for i in 0..<len" without using the i anymore...Xcode will show an warning on the line...Check that.

Comment: @redisky notice how Code Different eliminated the C-style for loops? The approach he demonstrated is the preferred approach. Take note that in Swift 3 the C-Style for loop will be deprecated. source: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Answer (score -2):

if you want to filter prime numbers from an array use this code:

```
          let primeNumbers = myArray.filter { number in
            if number == 0 {
              return false
              }
            return number % 2 == 0
            }
```

Comment: 4 is not a prime number and passes this lol.